# Monitor/Track data sent over internet by an application

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitoring

How do I monitor/track (and possibly save) the data that is **sent** over the internet by an application?

Example: I have an application "X", it sends some data over the internet, now I want to know what it sent and to whom (or which server). How to do this?

The required things would be, What is sent? To which IP:Port? To which Location/URL?

Also I would like to **repeat** the network request.

I tried TCPview, but it only tells about the IP:Port and nothing else. I also tried Wireshark, but didn't help to get the results (or maybe I missed some options). If this is possible with wireshark, it would be nice.

---

**Update 1**: I also tried Fiddler 2, which is awesome for sniffing HTTP traffic but not what I want to do.

I want to sniff traffic on an IP with port 2100 (amiganetfs), someone said sniffing is possible with Wireshark, but HOW?

---

I want to do this with an application that seems malicious to me. Any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an understanding of TCP/UDP and IP protocols to use packet sniffers like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which if you do then that can tell you what it’s sending, also have a look at Process Monitor at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: How would that help me to sniff **network** data?? (talking about process monitor)

Comment: Could you help me attaining the task with wireshark?

Comment: All you really need to do is download Wireshark and run. You can filter data via IP, Data type, port and more.

Comment: I have done that (of course). Now, I choose the adapter and started monitoring. I can see the new requests coming in, I have captured the requests (and also stopped it after enough logging) but how do I figure out the data? Lets say, I got a request of a PNG image (via chrome), how do I save it without opening it in a new window? Also does it show the GET, POST, HEAD requests with parameters?

Comment: maybe [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qlc0Wwnwxrs) helps you a bit

Comment: That video is just too basic, I know all that. The thing is that on port 2100, I am unable to view the traffic. Fiddler has all the things I want but doesn't work with custom ports. Wireshark shows the requests, but I am unable to read them.